# watir element click intercepted:

Tags: ruby, watir

I'm trying to click on a button that contains the words "Add To Cart" using ruby/watir.

If I use

```
cart = browser.link(text: 'Add To Cart') 
if cart.present?
   cart.click
```

It works (item gets added to cart) but I get a element click intercepted: Element ... is not clickable at point (441, 20). Other element would receive the click: (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementClickInterceptedError

I'm new to ruby/watir so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: here is the element I'm trying to read <div class="btn primary wishlist_cart_button" id="WC_CatalogEntryDBThumbnailDisplayJSPF_3074457345618797276_add_div_1">
          
  <a class="" href="javascript: setCurrentId('WC_CatalogEntryDBThumbnailDisplayJSPF_3074457345618797276_links_1'); categoryDisplayJS.AddItem2ShopCartAjax('3074457345618797276',1);" id="WC_CatalogEntryDBThumbnailDisplayJSPF_3074457345618797276_links_1">Add To Cart</a>
 
         </div>

Answer (score 2):

Try this code whether it works. If it's not working then as you have stated, even after the error, it works, So I assume we have to issue the click on the element which is overlaying the target element. So Paste the entire error message. The error message must contain the element which is actually obscuring.

```
require 'watir'
b = Watir::Browser.new
cart = browser.link(text: 'Add To Cart')
if cart.present?
  b.wait_while { cart.obscured? }
  cart.click
end
```

**Update**

Okay, there are other two ways you have to try.

One is to use JavaScript.

```
cart.click!
```

Or click the element which is overlaying your element.From your error the element is division with class attribute 'row'. If you have more detail about that element, you can locate that element by yourself. But now, with the given detail, I form the locator.

```
b.div(class: 'row').click
```

Comment: Still got an error. here it is element click intercepted: Element <div id="section_list_wishlists" class="facetSelectContainer" role="group" aria-expanded="true" aria-labelledby="section_button_wishlists">...</div> is not clickable at point (441, 20). Other element would receive the click: <div class="row">...</div> (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementClickInterceptedError)
  (Session info: chrome=86.0.4240.198)

Comment: @ggenovez I have updated the answer. Check and let me know.

Comment: I tried the click! and received the same error. that other element is a side menu. Selecting it would bring me to a different page. not sure why there is overlap. it does not have an "Add To Cart" text associated.

Comment: image of element [link](https://photos.app.goo.gl/YEoaz8vQb25Em32Y9) any other ways to search for the button element? cart = browser.div(class: 'btn.primary.wishlist_cart_button') never finds the element.

Comment: Can you give me the url?

Answer (score 0):

there are few ways you can figure what is going on

try looking around the element

check if watir sees more than one link, this should produce 1

`browser.as(text: 'Add To Cart').count`

then try to click every element if it has more than 1

`browser.as(text: 'Add To Cart')[0].click`

`browser.as(text: 'Add To Cart')[1].click`

or try to click its parent, link can be behind overlay

`browser.a(text: 'Add To Cart').parent.click`

then check if same can be acomplished by clicking parent element directly

`browser.div(class: 'wishlist_cart_button').click`

or you can try with different approach, find element by some other attribute

`browser.a(href: /setCurrentId/).click`

also maybe there is a parent element with id so you can find the cart button easier

`browser.element(id: "asdf").a(text: "Add To Cart").click`

`browser.element(id: "asdf").as.last.click`

if everything above fails, then click it with selenium, since watir is worried about click being intercepted

`browser.driver.action.move_to(browser.a(text: 'Add To Cart').wd).click.perform`

hope something helps :D